# Eliminar datos de mysql sin recargar la pagina

Tags: datos, eliminar

este es mi proyecto donde se esta realizando un sistema de cotizacion

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el problema es en la segunda foto, realmente deseo eliminar los item 1, 2, o los que se agreguen de esta tabla sin que se cambie el url o en pocas palabras sin que se recargue la pagina, ya que cada url tiene un id donde los datos cambian, solo me faltaria eso para poder culminar este proyecto si neceitan mas informacion acerca de este proyecto estoy al tanto gracias por ayuda la verdad soy nuevo en esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este de aqui abajo en mi codigo donde se muestra los datos de las cotizaciones de la tabla enlazada a phpmyadmin si desean mas informacion estoy atento

```
    <?php

    require_once ("conexion.php");//Contiene funcion que conecta a la base de datos
    include("funciones.php");
    
    $active_productos="active";


    if (isset($_POST['descripcion']) and isset($_POST['cantidad'])){
        $cotizacion_id=intval($_GET['id']);
        $descripcion=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,(strip_tags($_POST["descripcion"],ENT_QUOTES)));
        $o_t=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,(strip_tags($_POST["o_t"],ENT_QUOTES)));
        $cantidad=intval($_POST['cantidad']);
        $unidad=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,(strip_tags($_POST["unidad"],ENT_QUOTES)));
        $unitario=floatval($_POST['unitario']);
    
        $guardar=guardar_historial($cotizacion_id, $descripcion, $o_t, $cantidad, $unidad, $unitario);

        if ($guardar==1){
            $message=1;
        } else {
            $error=1;
        }
    }

    if (isset($_GET['id'])){
        $cotizacion_id=intval($_GET['id']);
        $query=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from cotizaciones where cotizacion_id='$cotizacion_id'");
        $row=mysqli_fetch_array($query);
        
    } else {
        die("Producto no existe");
    }
    
?>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Cotizaciones Inoxpetrol S.A.S</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilo.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/pru.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <script src="sweetalert2.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="sweetalert2.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
</head>

  <body>




        <?php
        }
        ?>  


                <table style="font-family: Mukta, sans-serif;">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Item</td>
                            <td>Descripción</td>
                            <td>o.t</td>
                            <td>Cantidad</td>
                            <td>Unidad</td>
                            <td>VR. Unidad</td>
                            <td>VR. Total</td>              
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>

                    <?php
                        $tax=19;
                        $items=1;
                        $suma=0;
                        $cotizaciones_id=intval($_GET['id']);
                        $query=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from item where cotizacion_id='$cotizacion_id'");
                        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){

                        $total=$row['item_cantidad']*$row['item_vr_unidad'];
                        $total=number_format($total,3,);
                    ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $items;?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['item_descripcion'];?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['item_o_t'];?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['item_cantidad'];?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['item_unidad'];?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['item_vr_unidad'];?></td>
                            <td class="status-paid"><?php  echo $total?></td>                           
                            <td class="accion"><a href="#" onclick="deleteb('<?php echo $row['item_id'];?>');" title='Borrar Inventario'> <i class="bi bi-trash accions"></i></i></a></td> 



                        </tr>       
                    <?php
                    $items++;
                    $suma+=$total;

                    }

                    $iva=$suma * ($tax / 100);
                    $total_iva=number_format($iva,3,'.','');    
                    $total=$suma + $total_iva;

                    ?>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/cotizacion.js"></script>     
    <script type="module" src="js/fk.js"></script>

    
  
  </body>
  </div>
</html>
<script>


</script>
```

Comment: Debes trabajar tu codigo con AJAX-PHP-MySQL. Te invito a que investigues mas sobre esto y te dejo un [link](https://www.baulphp.com/usando-ajax-con-php-mysql-ejemplos/) que te puede ayudar con lo que quieres hacer